# How to get data from string after particular backslash?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a string such as `\home\var\path\uplaod\abc.png`. Now I want to get data from **uplaod** onwards. Please suggest any function or code?

Comment: Describe it in detail.

Comment: what you have tried? Please add here.

Comment: What is the expected result? `uplaod\abc.png`? `abc.png`? Please explain with details.

Comment: uplaod\abc.png i want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If path of image is not fixed or order of `uplaod` is not specific try like this.

```
let string = "\\home\\var\\path\\uplaod\\abc.png"
if let range = string.range(of: "uplaod") {
    let imagePath = string.substring(from: range.lowerBound)
    print(imagePath)
}
```

**Output**

```
uplaod\abc.png
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let string = "\\home\\var\\path\\uplaod\\abc.png"

let parts = string.components(separatedBy: "\\")

parts // ["", "home", "var", "path", "uplaod", "abc.png"]
```

Any of the elements of this array you can get by its index.

```
parts[4..<parts.count].joined(separator: "\\") // "uplaod\\abc.png"
```